# Concatting Lines into List of strings

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

I have a text file (that has been loaded into a list for each new line) that I am working with.. its format is something like this:

```
***CP6***
UNIT, PARTS
    some data here
    some more data here
        more data1
        more data2
    etc111
        etc222
    etc333
    etc444
    etc555
UNIT, PARTS
    11111
    22222
        2.1
        2.2
        2.3
    33333
and so on....
```

I would like to grab the lines between each `UNIT, PARTS` and concat it onto a single line to look like this:

```
theList[0] = UNIT, PARTS\n\tsome data here\n\tsome more data here\n\t\tmore data1\n\t\tmore data2\n\tetc111\n\t\tetc222\n\tetc333\n\tetc444\n\tetc555
theList[1] = UNIT, PARTS\n\t11111\n\t22222\n\t\t2.1\n\t\t2.2\n\t\t2.3\n\t33333
theList[n] = UNIT, PARTS\n\t.......
```

Can anyone help me with this?

### EDIT:

The data is in a List.. So I was thinking something like `foreach (var item in fileLineList)`...

### EDIT2:

I have been messing around and have come up with this.. but it does not seem to work how I intended it to...

```
                foreach (var line in tempList1)
                {

                    if (isUnitPart == false)
                    {
                        if (line.ToUpper().Contains("\"UNIT\",\"PARTS\""))
                            isUnitPart = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (line.ToUpper().Contains("\"UNIT\",\"PARTS\""))
                            isUnitPart = false;
                    }

                    if (isUnitPart == true)
                        concattedUnitPart = concattedUnitPart + line;

                    else
                    {
                        theList.Add(concattedUnitPart + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: every item should start with UNIT, PARTS or python indentation style?

Comment: @sleimanjneidi: Every item should start with `UNIT, PARTS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var units = new Regex("UNIT, PARTS",RegexOptions.Multiline)
          .Split(myString)
           .Where(c=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)).ToArray();
```

Comment: But the delimiter itself("UNIT, PARTS") will be removed from the returned array. That is not what the OP has asked for.

Answer (score 1):

`myString.Split(new string[]{"UNIT, PARTS"}, StringSplitOptions.None)` will give you

```
theList[0] = \n\tsome data here\n\tsome more data here\n\t\tmore data1\n\t\tmore data2\n\tetc111\n\t\tetc222\n\tetc333\n\tetc444\n\tetc555
theList[1] = \n\t11111\n\t22222\n\t\t2.1\n\t\t2.2\n\t\t2.3\n\t33333
theList[n] = \n\t....
```

which is probably what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [ReadAllText](http://ReadAllText) to get all lines in a single `string`.

**Edit**: If all your data is in a List:

```
string[] input = IO.File.ReadAllLines(path); //or a List<String>  
string[] delimiter = new[] { "UNIT, PARTS" };
string text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, input);
var lines = from word in text.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.None)      
            select line = (delimiter[0] + word)
```

You need to prefix the result words with the delimiter itself because `String.Split` removes the delimiter from the returned array.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx

Comment: I get an error on the delimiter stating: `Cannont initialize an implicitly-typed local variable with an array initializer.`

Comment: I didn't know that this won't compile [in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/bluffersguide3.aspx) since it's no problem in VB.NET(normally VB is more verbose). This was manually converted from VB. Edited my answer accordingly.